# How to use the $in operator with SequelizeJS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, in-operator

I'm trying to use the $in operator in SequelizeJS as you would in a MySQL statement:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1, value2, ...);
```

In my case, I've joined three tables, but I don't believe that's related to the issue. I keep getting this error `Error: Invalid value { '$in': ['12345','67890','15948'] }` with the following code:

```
definedTable.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: definedTableTwo,
    where: {
      zip_code: {
        $in: ['12345','67890','15948']
      }
    },
    required: true,
    plain: true
  },
  {
    model: definedTableThree,
    required: true,
    plain: true
  }]
})
```

Can someone provide some insight on how to use the $in operator? The only examples I've seen are with integers within the array when searching Ids.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just reading the docs here [Sequelize WHERE](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#where)

I'd try :

```
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
definedTable.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: definedTableTwo,
    where: {
      zip_code: {
        [Op.in]: ['12345','67890','15948']
          }
    },
    required: true,
    plain: true
  },
  {
    model: definedTableThree,
    required: true,
    plain: true
  }]
})
```

Does that help ?

Comment: Hi @pierreaurelemartin, the `$in` is essentially `[Op.in]`. `$in` is an alias for that operator. I'm questioning whether I'm providing the values in the correct format. At least that is what the error indicates.

Comment: I just realized that the alias `$in` was **NOT** included in my file, that ended up being the issue. Basically user error. I'll mark your comment as the answer since it's technically correct and brought my user error to light. Thanks

Comment: Hey guys, I have the same problem. Instead, I need to add and condition on zip code. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Link to doc is broken. Found this https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#operators
It shows as well that this shorthand syntax `zip_code: ['12345','67890','15948']` should work too 