# NPM Sequelize, where: [list]

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Hey I am very new to working with sequelize ORM and I wasn't able to find out if I can use where in a findAll() with a list.

So here accountIds is a list of ids and the table I am searching I want to get any row where the accountId is in accountIds.  Is this the correct way to do this in sequelize?

```
.findAll({
  where: {
    accountId: [accountIds]
  }
})
```

Comment: It depends on the version you are using. What is the sequelize version?

Comment: The sequelize version is 6.11.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in this case as long as accountIds is an array then it will work no need to add anything else.

## Solution

```
.findAll({
  where: {
    accountId: accountIds
  }
})
```

Comment: If this is your solution, please mark it as the solution by the tick on the left hand side of the post.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your accountIds is an array.

```
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
 definedTable.findAll({
 where: {
      zip_code: {
        $in: accountIds
      }})
```

Go [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49700623/how-to-use-the-in-operator-with-sequelizejs) for more complex quires